# Black and white color addition

Tags: python, image, image-processing, graphics, signal-processing

When red is mixed with green, I  get yellow as expected.

```
RGB for Red:   [255, 0, 0] 
RGB for Green: [0, 255, 0]
Result:        [255, 255, 0]
```

But when white is mixed with black, I should get normally grey but I get white. Shouldn't I get grey?

```
RGB for Black: [0, 0, 0] 
RGB for White: [255, 255, 255]
Result:        [255, 255, 255]
```

Here is the code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops
import math
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

im1= Image.open(r'.\red.jpg')
im2= Image.open(r'.\green.jpg')

result = ImageChops.add(im1, im2)

plt.imshow(result)
```

Comment: White is `[255, 255, 255]` and black is `[0, 0, 0]` and therefore adding leads to white (`255 + 0 = 255`)?

Comment: Then what is the name of the operation to get gray? I thought adding white and black will bring me grey. It doesn't seem so.

Comment: I think you could use `ImageChops.constant(image, value)` (`value` is the greyness level). Afaik this is equivalent to `Image.new("L", image.size, value)`.

Comment: Mixing black and white yields gray if you mix paints, not if you mix lights. The RGB model is an additive model. Black is the absence of light, so adding it to any other color will have no effect on that color. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_color

Comment: If you want to get gray, average the white and black pixels together.

Comment: Basically adding is not "mixing", and when mixing, you can have several options on how to mix two colors, the answer below by @Shamshirsaz.Navid gives very good explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what @Cris Luengo said ("If you want to get gray, average the white and black pixels together") is valid; Also I think one additional thing can be a MixFactor.

You can use OpenCV for this.

Imports:

```py
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
```

Load image:

```py
im = cv2.imread(sys.path[0]+'/im.png')
```

Main code:

```py
color=[0,0,0]
mixFactor=.5
im = (1-mixFactor)*im+[(mixFactor)*x for x in color]
```

My input values for color:

```
[0, 0, 0] black
[255, 255, 255] white
[255, 0, 0] blue (BGR)
[0, 255, 0] green   
[0, 0, 255] red
```

I draw the first colorful image using a graphical software; The other 8 created with this Python code.

[image]

---

**Credit:** The text on the image is written using the default [Hershey](https://emergent.unpythonic.net/software/hershey) font included in OpenCV. And you can read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hershey_fonts) and [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga0f9314ea6e35f99bb23f29567fc16e11).

---

**Update:**
If you want to use imshow for the output of this blending method; use it like this:

```
cv2.imshow("preview", im/255)
```

Comment: Can you check my code pls? https://www.codepile.net/pile/VKmlpJYn     I am using Lena's classical .jpg image as a source. But can't make it work. I only get white output when mixed with 0.5 mixfactor. @Shamshirsaz.Navid

Comment: Hello @Lyrk :) There is no source code in your link. please double check this.

Comment: Ahh sorry for that. Here it is. https://www.online-python.com/0MuA42SbKY @Shamshirsaz.Navid

Comment: @Lyrk hello again :) try change the cv2.imshow("out", im/255)
cv2.imshow("out", im)

Comment: Or try to save the image using **imwrite** instead